# Group by in Shell for max date in a file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

From the below file, I am trying to select only those line that has latest `LAST_UPDATE` time for a given Stock.

So, here we have 3 lines for Stock TCS, so i want to print only that line that has highest value of `LAST_UPDATE`.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Input File:**

```
LAST_UPDATE,Stock,YOUR_PRICE,MY_PRICE 

04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669

05:00:07.405,TCS,2452.21,2453.8296

06:05:25.306,TATA,0,1320.0611

06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611

07:00:04.426,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037

07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

**Expected Output:**

```
LAST_UPDATE,Stock,YOUR_PRICE,MY_PRICE

04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669

06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611

07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

Comment: Is the list of stocks limited to INFY, TATA and TCS ?

Comment: No, that is just for simplicity. There could be any number of stocks and can have entry in the file multiple times.

Comment: Also what is the shell you are using ?

Comment: I am using KSH.

Comment: I can't test ksh. Does `sort -t, -u -k2,2 <(sort -r inputfile)` or `sort -r inputfile | sort -t, -u -k2,2` work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

**Script :**

```
#!/bin/ksh
tempfile="stocktemp"
mkdir $tempfile
# sort the time by stock in a temp file named by the stock name
while read line; do
        stock=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2`
        echo $line >> "$tempfile/$stock.txt"
done < inputfile
# Remove the line generated because of the top line in inputfile
rm $tempfile/Stock.txt
# in all the stock file ...
for file in $tempfile/*; do
        # (Init a comparitor)
        time="00:00:00"
        # ... we compare the time between the lines
        while read line; do
                # we select the time in the line where we removed the .xyz at the end (we don't need ms)
                comp=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1 | cut -d "." -f 1`
                # we compare the time converted in second
                if [ `echo $comp | sed s/:/*60+/g | bc` -gt `echo $time | sed s/:/*60+/g` ]; then
                time=$comp
                final=$line
                fi
        done < $file
        echo $final
done
rm -rf $tempfile
```

**Inputfile :**

```
LAST_UPDATE,Stock,YOUR_PRICE,MY_PRICE 

04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669

05:00:07.405,TCS,2452.21,2453.8296

06:05:25.306,TATA,0,1320.0611

06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611

07:00:04.426,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037

07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

**Test :**

```
Will /home/will # ./script.ksh
04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669
06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611
07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

Not the cleanest but it works. If you want to get the results in a file you can change `echo $final` by `echo $final >> output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- a `awk` solution is acceptable
- input file may not (already) be sorted by time stamp
- output is to be sorted alphabetically by stock/symbol name (special case: the 'Stock' line is always printed first)
- blank lines are to be skipped/ignored in the output (otherwise solution can be edited to add a blank line between output lines)

One possible `awk` solution:

```
$ cat find_last.awk
$2=="Stock" { print ; next }            # print "Stock" line when we find it; skip "NF==4" processing by going to next line in file

NF==4       { lastline[$2]=$0 }         # if field count (NF) = 4 then store latest line for $2=symbol in associative array;
                                        # has added benefit that it ignores blank lines

END { n = asorti(lastline, x)           # sort our array indices (aka symbol names); 'n' = count of indices; x[] array of indices

      for ( i=1 ; i<=n; i++ ) {         # loop through our list of n array indices (aka symbol names)

          print lastline[x[i]]          # print the (last/greatest) line for a stock/symbol
      }
    }
```

- `END { ... }` : performed (once) after the input file has been processed

Our sample input file (including blank lines as per in the original question):

```
$ cat infile
LAST_UPDATE,Stock,YOUR_PRICE,MY_PRICE

04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669

05:00:07.405,TCS,2452.21,2453.8296

06:05:25.306,TATA,0,1320.0611

06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611

07:00:04.426,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037

07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

The `awk` script in action:

```
$ sort infile | awk -F, -f find_last.awk
LAST_UPDATE,Stock,YOUR_PRICE,MY_PRICE
04:19:44.314,INFY,146.766,146.7669
06:05:27.184,TATA,0,1320.0611
07:00:08.022,TCS,2463.8,2463.8037
```

- `sort infile | awk ...` : sort input file by time stamp, pipe output to `awk` command
- `-F,` : set input field separator to a comma (,)
- `-f find_last.awk` : use `awk` commands from the file named `find_last.awk`